# Client side authentication with jax-rs and cxf

Tags: java, jersey, cxf, jax-rs

We are going to switch JAX-RS implementation from Jersey to Apache CXF 3.0. I just can't figure out how basic authentication is done the Apache CXF way. All examples I found where around CXF `WebClient`, not the JAX-RS Client API.

This is what's working with Jersey:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.register(HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic(config.getUsername(),config.getPassword()));
```

How can this be done with Apache CXF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a [`ClientRequestFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientRequestFilter.html) to perform the basic authentication:

```
@Provider
public class Authenticator implements ClientRequestFilter {

    private String user;
    private String password;

    public Authenticator(String user, String password) {
        this.user = user;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        requestContext.getHeaders().add(
            HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, getBasicAuthentication());
    }

    private String getBasicAuthentication() {
        String userAndPassword = this.user + ":" + this.password;
        byte[] userAndPasswordBytes = userAndPassword.getBytes("UTF-8");
        return "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(userAndPasswordBytes);
    }
}
```

And register it in your [`Client`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html):

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient().register(new Authenticator(user, password));
```

The solution above uses the Java 8 [`Base64.Encoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html) to perform the Base64 encoding.
If, for some reason, you are not using Java 8, you can use [`BaseEncoding`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html) from [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava).

Answer (score 0):

I've opened an improvement in CXF Jira for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6817

Comment: There you are, just 4 rep away from being able to post comments... which this should be, as it's not an answer. Just a couple of suggested edits, and you're home free!